# Gnome shell system extensions

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

Do anyone know how to remove stubborn Gnome shell extensions? For some reason certain extensions are marked as system extensions, to be removed only by the system administrator using the package manager. That's OK as long as the extensions load and work (they can always be deactivated if unwanted). The problem is when the extension doesn't even load, then it can not be deactivated, and you end up with an ugly "error" when viewing the list of installed extensions. This happens on one of my computers with the "Applications menu" extension. It doesn't really do any harm, but I don't like it when things throw up errors that can't be corrected. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh well, I found a solution myself: these so-called system extensions are loaded from the directory `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` on startup, most of them aptly named so you can find which is which.

So it's a simple exercise – go to the directory I mentioned, do a `sudo rm -r <culprit>`, log out and in again, and voila! Gone :)